# Lettergame in C ending early

Tags: c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXGUESSES 5
                                                            // function declarations
void GameRules();
int SingleGame(char file_letter);
char RetrieveGuess();
int GuessedIt(char answer, char input_letter);
int main()
{
    int PlayGames = 0,                                      //Variable Declarations
        i = 0;                                              //Variable Declarations
    char correctanswer;                                     //Variable Declarations

    GameRules();                                            //Call of GameRules Function
    FILE *fp;                                               //Opening File
    fp = fopen("lettersin", "r");                           //Opening File for Reading
    printf("How many games would you like to play?1-4:");   //Prompting for Number of Games to Play
    scanf("&d", &PlayGames);                                //Scanning number of games wished to be played, storing it in PlayGames 
    for (i = 0; i<PlayGames; i++)                           //For Loop that lasts until i=playgames
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%c", &correctanswer);                   //function to scan 1 letter from lettersin.txt
        int SingleGame(correctanswer);                      //Play one game
        if (SingleGame == 1)                                //if Single Game returns 1, you win
        {
            printf("You Win!");
        }
        else if (SingleGame == 0)                           //If Single Game returns 0, you lose
        {
            printf("You Lose");
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);                                             //Closes the File
    return 0;
}

void GameRules()                                            //Function that prints the Rules
{
    printf("This is the Letter Game. The goal is to guess the correct letter within 5 attempts. After each guess you will be told whether the letter you attempted to guess comes before or after the letter actually guessed.\n");
}

char RetrieveGuess()                                        //Function to prompt for a guess, then store the guess in an integer that is returned by the function when called
{
    char a;
    printf("Enter a letter");
    scanf("%c", &a);
    return a;
}

int GuessedIt(char answer, char input_letter)               //Function that returns 1 when the answer is correct, or suggests where the correct answer is if the guess is incorrect
{
    if (answer == input_letter)                             //if the guess is the same as the answer, return 1
    { 
        return 1; 
    }
    else if (answer > input_letter)                         //if the guess is incorrect, suggest on how to improve and return 0
    { 
        printf("the correct letter comes before your guess"); return 0; 
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("the correct letter comes after your guess"); return 0;
    }

}


int SingleGame(char file_letter)                            //Function to play 1 game
{
    int numGuesses = 0;                                     //Variable Declarations
    char b;
    while (numGuesses < MAXGUESSES)                         //While Loop that repeats until numguesses=maxguesses
    {
        b=RetrieveGuess();                                  //sets b equal to the value RetrieveGuess returns
        GuessedIt(file_letter, b);                          //uses b and whichever value is entered into SingleGame to determine wheter the answer is correct
        if (GuessedIt == 1)                                 //If function that returns 1 if the guess is correct and ends the function, otherwise it increments numguesses
        {
            return 1;
            numGuesses = 6;
        }
        else numGuesses = numGuesses++;                     //increments numguesses to end loop after 5 guesses

    }
    if (numGuesses == 5)                                    //returns 0 if the letter is not guessed within 5 tries
    {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

When I try to run my code, I'm getting no error messages, but my code ends after i enter the amount of games i would like to play. There are no errors, other than 'cannot find or open PDB File' and I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Express

Comment: No error messages at runtime? But you *do* get (4) compiler warnings, so please deal with them first. One example: `if (SingleGame == 1) ` where that is a function identifier, not a function call.

Comment: i fixed the first 2, but i can't figure out what  warning 'C4715: 'SingleGame' : not all control paths return a value' is

Comment: When `if (numGuesses == 5) ` is false, no value is returned. Did you want `return numGuesses != 5;`? Just a guess ;)

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )  Note: the compiler outputs two `error` message and several warnings for the posted code,  So even if you did not enable the warnings, it does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

It's `scanf("%d", &PlayGames);` (change the &d by %d)

Answer (score 0):

In the main function you are using singlegame- function name as a variable...it should throw an error because you have'nt declared any such variable..instead place the function call 
singlegame(correctanswer) in the if and else condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should not compile at all. I'm surprised you claim it does. You are using functions as if they were variables.

But in any case, after fixing all those things the code does indeed end prematurely. The cause is a typo in `scanf("&d", &PlayGames);`. The int format specifier should read `%d` instead of `&d`.

Because of this typo the value of PlayGames is never set and stays at 0.